# Pass to form and edit pivot data for single instance of ManyToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Been searching for **Laravel** / **Livewire** examples of how to show and edit pivot data on a form for a single instance of a **ManyToMany** relationship.

for example "documents has many materials - materials has many documents, pivot table has extra columns "item & quantity".

I have already built a index view and can attach/sync/detach materials to documents.

I want to be able to view and update pivot fields on a form individually for each material item that is connected to document.

I am completely new at all this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->document->materials(); //get all the materials related to the document

$this->document->materials()->find($id); //get a material by id

$material = $this->document->materials()-find($id);
$material->update([...]);
```

Comment: That does not include the extra pivot columns